# How can I preseed package installation without a network connection?

Tags: package-management, preseed, custom-distributions, offline

I am working to create an unattended offline installation of the Ubuntu Server 12.04.

I have everything preseeded so far, but I still can't figure out how to install other packages without requiring a network connection.

I would like to install puppet, and give it a personal configuration, but all of this should be done without requiring a network connection. How can this be done?

How can I add a package to the distribution?

Thank You in advance! :)